# How to run maven commands as background process in power shell

Tags: powershell, maven, spring-boot

I have few spring boot projects that I need to run using power shell in jenkins. I am able to do it partially on my local with following command  -

```
mvn -f $repoLocation -D "spring-boot.run.profiles=e2e" -DskipTests=true spring-boot:run
```

The problem with this is that as soon as the first project runs, it just keeps waiting for it and doesn't move to the next one. That is, it doesn't run this command as a background process.

Any suggestions as how could I do that? I basically need to start the projects in order as contained in the `$repos` array.

Note - I tried to use `start process` as below, but it simply invoked it in a new command prompt and was able to run only the first one, similar to what I was able to achieve.

```
foreach ($element in $repos) {
    $repoLocation = $localPath + $element.Split('/')[-1]
    Write-Host('Maven build for ' + $repoLocation)
    start-process -FilePath mvn -ArgumentList ("-f $repoLocation -D `"spring-boot.run.profiles=prod`" -DskipTests=true spring-boot:run") -Wait
    #mvn -f $repoLocation -D "spring-boot.run.profiles=prod" -DskipTests=true spring-boot:run
    Write-Host('Maven build completed for ' + $repoLocation)
    $repoLocation = ''
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to reference the following blog post...

[Parallel processing with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/06/20/parallel-processing-with-powershell/)

You'll want to skip-to the sections on Powershell jobs. Your job might look something like this...

```
## Using Jobs...
$repositories = $(...)

foreach ($repository in $repositories) {
    Start-Job `
        -Name "build-${repository}" `
        -Scriptblock {
            param($repository)
            mvn --file .\${repository}\xml.pom -D "spring-boot.run.profiles=e2e" -DskipTests=true spring-boot:run } `
        -ArgumentList $repository
}
```

Your maven call will be probably be different, but you get the idea of where I'm going. The `Start-Job` kicks off the operation async.

There is a wealth of material on Powershell jobs, I won't duplicate that effort here.

Powershell workflows (also detailed in the article) might also suit your needs. 
If you dig a little deeper in the parallelization space, you start to read about runspaces. I like runspaces generally speaking but not for what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It worked like a charm, just that I had to modify the script block like `-ScriptBlock { param($repository).....` else it wasn't picking up passed params for me. Thanks so much.